# How to make a custom hook to show a delete message

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';<br>
import { Button, message } from 'antd';<br>
const key = 'updatable';<br>
export const useDeleteMessage = (message1 , message2) => {

    const [state, setstate] = useState(null)
    const openMessage = (message1,message2) => {
        message.loading({
          content: message1,
          key,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          message.success({
            content: message2,
            key,
            duration: 2,
          });
        }, 1000);
      };
       return (
          openMessage(message1 ,message2)
         )
};

card.js<br>
const card =()=>{
   return(
onClick={useDeleteMessage('loading' , 'loadedworking')}>button</p>
   )
}
```

i want to call this hook like this so that on click on any particular button i want to show the message ,the above code only executing on reloding , after reloading the page the message is showing , please suggest how can i correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't bind the hook on onClick function
2. Your hook returns a function

Use the below code:

1. Return the function and update hook parameters

   ```
    export const useDeleteMessage = () => {
      const openMessage = (message1, message2) => {
        message.loading({
          content: message1,
          key,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          message.success({
            content: message2,
            key,
            duration: 2,
          });
        }, 1000);
      };

      return openMessage;      
   };
   ```
2. Update onClick

   ```
   const card =()=>{
      const openMessage = useDeleteMessage();
      return(
        <button onClick={() => openMessage('loading' , 'loadedworking')}>button</p>
      )
   }
   ```